# Check if installation or upgrade in custom action

Tags: wix, wix3.5

How can I check in C# custom action if msi is installing or upgrading? Is there a session property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the WiX majorupgrade element then the  WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED  property is set if you doing an install and it's going to upgrade.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html

The property is set by the FindRelatedProducts action, so your custom action must be after that. If you're just doing a fresh install it won't be set.